# Android Google Maps API keeps going outdoor

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I've been trying to use Google Maps Indoor API to show the route between 2 markers in a certain mall. I got my references from this URL:

http://www.akexorcist.com/2015/12/google-direction-library-for-android-en.html

The problem is, the route calculated by the Google Maps API keeps going outdoor instead of staying indoor. I've set the setIndoorEnabled(true) but it doesn't do anything to my map. I've also set the transport mode to walking to make sure it can go through the mall area. Is there anything I should do to force the route to go indoor?

Here's the code I used from the link I mentioned above (modified to show the specific location)

```
package com.akexorcist.googledirection.sample;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.akexorcist.googledirection.DirectionCallback;
import com.akexorcist.googledirection.GoogleDirection;
import com.akexorcist.googledirection.constant.AvoidType;
import com.akexorcist.googledirection.constant.TransitMode;
import com.akexorcist.googledirection.constant.TransportMode;
import com.akexorcist.googledirection.model.Direction;
import com.akexorcist.googledirection.util.DirectionConverter;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SimpleDirectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, View.OnClickListener, DirectionCallback {
    private Button btnRequestDirection;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private String serverKey = "AIzaSyBOcJvN0oJtosmdxR3H3RyCkAhrxmLYJMc";
    //private LatLng camera = new LatLng(-6.1955864, 106.8202085);
    private LatLng camera = new LatLng(-6.1777736, 106.7914177);
    //private LatLng origin = new LatLng(-6.1955864, 106.8202085);
    //private LatLng destination = new LatLng(-6.1947805, 106.8199912);
    LatLng origin = new LatLng(-6.1777736, 106.7914177);
    LatLng destination = new LatLng(-6.1769235, 106.791584);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple_direction);

        btnRequestDirection = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_request_direction);
        btnRequestDirection.setOnClickListener(this);

        ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(camera, 18));
        googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        if (id == R.id.btn_request_direction) {
            requestDirection();
        }
    }

    public void requestDirection() {
        Snackbar.make(btnRequestDirection, "Direction Requesting...", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        GoogleDirection.withServerKey(serverKey)
                .from(origin)
                .to(destination)
                .transportMode(TransportMode.WALKING)
                .execute(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDirectionSuccess(Direction direction, String rawBody) {
        Snackbar.make(btnRequestDirection, "Success with status : " + direction.getStatus(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (direction.isOK()) {
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(origin));
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(destination));

            ArrayList<LatLng> directionPositionList = direction.getRouteList().get(0).getLegList().get(0).getDirectionPoint();
            googleMap.addPolyline(DirectionConverter.createPolyline(this, directionPositionList, 5, Color.RED));

            btnRequestDirection.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDirectionFailure(Throwable t) {
        Snackbar.make(btnRequestDirection, t.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: original code created by Akexorcist

Comment: using `setIndoorEnabled` does not mean you get indoor directions, all that means is you get indoor maps. https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setIndoorEnabled(boolean). Either contact the person who wrote the Google Direction library you are using or look through the Directions API documentation and see if you can get indoor directions